Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint in the referenced table
I have two tables in MySQL, 'orders' and 'rota' and I am trying to connect the 'created_date' column from 'orders' with 'date' from table 'rota' using a foreign key.
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `row_id` int  NOT NULL ,
    `order_id` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
    `created_date` datetime  NOT NULL ,
    `item_id` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
    `quantity` int  NOT NULL ,
    `customer_id` int  NOT NULL ,
    `delivery` boolean  NOT NULL ,
    `address_id` int  NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        `row_id`
    )
);

CREATE TABLE `rota` (
    `row_id` int  NOT NULL ,
    `rota_id` varchar(20)  NOT NULL ,
    `date` datetime  NOT NULL ,
    `shift_id` varchar(20)  NOT NULL ,
    `staff_id` varchar(20)  NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        `row_id`
    )
);

ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_created_date` 
FOREIGN KEY(`created_date`)
REFERENCES `rota` (`date`);

Here is the error:

Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
index for constraint 'fk_orders_created_date' in the referenced table
'rota'    0.000 sec

